# Excel is returning the date in a sentence to the serial number instead of the actual date

Tags: excel, date

My formula takes various changing data from various cells and inputs them into a sentence that I can copy and paste into another program. However, the date in cell "I83" (This date changes from form to form, won't always be today) returns as the serial code for the date.

My current formula returns a sentence based on cell "I72".

`=IF(I72=4,""&B83&" - Taking an overall impact of "&I72&"% increase to the previous rates based on a PI of "&B44&" with "&C45&" bills pulling since "&C43&"",""&B83&" - Taking an overall impact of "&I72&"% increase to the previous rates [when run through the rater] based on a PI of "&B44&" with "&C45&" bills pulling since "&C43&"")`

B83 = Todays date (this auto populates the day the report is pulled)

C43 = changing date (this works now as TEXT and I manually enter this)

Comment: That works, however now the last bit of my formula that is suppose to return Today's date doesn't format properly. It ends with "This takes into effect 7/5/2022" as I'm currently using ```=Today()``` in that particular cell

Comment: So do `text(B83,"m/d/yy"`? And same for C43.

Answer (score 0):

`=CONCATENATE(TEXT(I39,"mm/dd/yyyy"), " ", J39)`

the `TEXT(cell, format)` will convert it to fit your need